# Process Out of memory while running Protractor Perf

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor-perf to measure performance for my angular application.

I am using `perfRunner.start();` and `perfRunner.stop();` in two places. When it's called the first time it works well, but the second time it's trigging an error:

> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> 77396 ms: Scavenge 1183.3 (1223.3) -> 1183.3 (1223.3) MB, 0.1 / 0 ms
>   (+ 2.0 m s in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental
>   marking delaying m ark-sweep]. 77739 ms: Mark-sweep 1183.3 (1223.3) ->
>   928.7 (969.4) MB, 342.7 / 0 ms (+ 2.0 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 2.0 ms) [last resort gc]. 78064 ms: Mark-sweep
>   928.7 (969.4) -> 928.7 (969.4) MB, 325.2 / 0 ms [last re sort gc].
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> Security context: 000000BE60A373A9  2: /* anonymous /(aka / anonymous
>   */) [D:\Automation\ProtractDemo\node_mod ules\protractor-perf\node_modules\browser-perf\node_modules\wd\lib\utils.js:~102
>   ] pc=000003E4A4F230BF 3: times
>   [D:\Automation\ProtractDemo\node_modules\protractor-perf\node_modul
>   es\browser-perf\node_modules\wd\node_modules\lodash\index.js:~11490]
>   [pc=000003E 4A50...
>
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of
>   memory

**Code Snippet for second call--**

```
perfRunner.start();
element(by.id('quote_owner:first_name')).sendKeys('Test');
browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="quote_owner:postal_code"]')).sendKeys('1000');
element(by.id('quote_owner:birth_date')).click();
```

I have already found a solution about increasing heap size using

> --max_old_space_size

**But i am not finding a way to set it in Protractor / Protractor-Perf environment. 
Please suggest **